# How to transform a Class Component to a Function Stateless Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I'm trying to transform a class component to function component. But it is a little bit dificult to me. Could you help me?

I've tried to do this, but it hasn´t worked:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import MovieCardsList from './MovieCardsList';

function (
  props.profiles
  props.movies
  props.users
) {
 return (
      <div>
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">ReactND - Coding Practice</h1>
        </header>
        <h1>How Popular is Your Favorite Movie?</h1>
        <MovieCardsList profiles={profiles} movies={movies} users={users} />
      </div>
    ); 
  }

export default App;
```

Here a part of the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import MovieCardsList from './MovieCardsList';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">ReactND - Coding Practice</h1>
        </header>
        <h1>How Popular is Your Favorite Movie?</h1>
        <MovieCardsList profiles={profiles} movies={movies} users={users} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Am I close to the solution? Any help, I appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: dont you have to name the function?
function App(){...}

Comment: @skyboyer, maybe it is oversimplified. I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minimal changes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import MovieCardsList from './MovieCardsList';

function App(props) {
   return (
      <div>
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">ReactND - Coding Practice</h1>
        </header>
        <h1>How Popular is Your Favorite Movie?</h1>
        <MovieCardsList profiles={props.profiles} movies={props.movies} users={props.users} />
      </div>
    ); 
  }

export default App;
```

You could also use `{...props}` object spread to set them on MovieCardsList or object deconstruction `({ profiles, movies, users })` to replace `(props)`. How I personally would do it:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import MovieCardsList from './MovieCardsList';

export default ({ profiles, movies, users }) => (
  <div>
    <header className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <h1 className="App-title">ReactND - Coding Practice</h1>
    </header>
    <h1>How Popular is Your Favorite Movie?</h1>
    <MovieCardsList profiles={profiles} movies={movies} users={users} />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Dillan, I've used the first one. It's worked. Thanks.

Comment: No problem! Always remember the basics. The mistakes I saw were functional definition (name your function and define it's parameters correctly). Best of luck!

Comment: I am new in the dev world. I have much to learn here from you, guys. Regards.

Comment: Welcome! Hope you like it. It can be equal parts exciting/rewarding and equal parts frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Either accept props as an argument:

```
function App = (props) => {
    cosnt {profiles, movies, users} = props
    return <div/>
}
```

or de-structure them right away

```
function App = ({profiles, movies, users}) => {
    return <div/>
}
```

Full Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import MovieCardsList from './MovieCardsList';

function App = ({profiles, movies, users}) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">ReactND - Coding Practice</h1>
        </header>
        <h1>How Popular is Your Favorite Movie?</h1>
        <MovieCardsList profiles={profiles} movies={movies} users={users} />
      </div>
    );
}
```

export default App;